# Need to create azure container sas token and list the containers

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Need to create azure container sas token and list the containers.

I’m trying to create sas token for Azure blob containers and list the containers using node.js

```
const startDate = new Date();

const expiryDate = new Date(startDate);

expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 30);

const permissions = new BlobSASPermissions();

permissions.read = true;

const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({

    containerName: containerName,

    permissions: permissions,

    startsOn: startDate,

    expiresOn: expiryDate

}, sharedKeyCredential).toString();

console.log(`SAS token for container ${containerName}: ${sasToken}`);

const containerSasUrl = `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}?${sasToken}`;
```

Now using the container sas url, I can’t able to list the container could you please some one guide me to list the containers using sas token.

Comment: Hi @jack I think you are creating SAS token for a particular container if you need a list container you can create sastoken with the account level.

Comment: Thanks for quick response and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to list the Azure blob containers with SAS token using Node.js.

**Code:**

```
const { BlobServiceClient,generateAccountSASQueryParameters,AccountSASPermissions,AccountSASServices,AccountSASResourceTypes,StorageSharedKeyCredential,SASProtocol } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

const request = require('request');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

const accountName="xxxx"
const accountKey="xxxxxxx"

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
const sasOptions = {
        services: AccountSASServices.parse("btqf").toString(),          // blobs, tables, queues, files
        resourceTypes: AccountSASResourceTypes.parse("sco").toString(), // service, container, object
        permissions: AccountSASPermissions.parse("rwdl"),          // permissions
        protocol: SASProtocol.Https,
        startsOn: new Date(),
        expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + (10 * 60 * 1000)),   // 10 minutes
    };

   const sasToken = generateAccountSASQueryParameters(
        sasOptions,
        sharedKeyCredential 
    ).toString();

    console.log(`sasToken = '${sasToken}'\n`);

const url = `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&${sasToken}`;

request.get({
  url: url
}, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    xml2js.parseString(body, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        const containers = result.EnumerationResults.Containers[0].Container;
        console.log('Containers:');
        containers.forEach(container => {
          console.log(container.Name[0]);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The above code uses(**`azure/storage-blob, request, xml2js`**) packages and it generates an **`account SAS token`** for an Azure Blob Storage account and uses it to list the containers in the account. It sends a **`GET`** request to the storage account URL with the `comp=list` query parameter and the SAS token, and parses the response body to extract the container names.

**Output:**

```
sasToken = 'sv=2023-08-03&ss=btqf&srt=sco&spr=https&st=2023-12-14T07%3A55%3A49Z&se=2023-12-14T08%3A05%3A49Z&sp=rwdl&sig=xxxx

Containers:
azure-webjobs-hosts
azure-webjobs-secrets
container567
fde4500bb4-input-74227
fde4500bb4-singlexxxde-output-74227
ixx
test
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[List Containers (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2?tabs=microsoft-entra-id)